# How can I use TinyMCE components with SSL?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ssl, tinymce

I have a Ruby on Rails admin section protected by an SSL certificate. Unfortunately, TinyMCE is loaded from the `public/javascripts` directory. Because the site is loading an un-encrypted script, all functions that require a pop-up window do not work (specifically the HTML/link functionality). Is there a way I can override this in the browser?

If not, is my only course of action including the JavaScript files with SSL protection?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to avoid pop-up windows. You can use modal dialogues. Here is the relevant tinymce init confonfiguration parameter

```
dialog_type: "modal",
```

addionally, you will ned to make sure inlinepopups is loaded:

```
plugins: '...,paste,style,inlinepopups'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is only supported in IE as per their site.

Comment: This does not seem to be correct. I am using Firefox and using this setting opens a modal dialogue instead of a new window.

Comment: I'll give this another try today and report back with my findings.

Comment: I updated our Tiny MCE version to the latest and tested with the dialog_type. It doesn't seem to work on Chrome, Firefox, or Safari for me. If you could provide a working sample of your code, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here is a working tinymce fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/R7caab . I used Firefox. You may click the html button and verify using Firebug that the dialog opened is a modal dialog and not a window

Comment: Thank you! Finally figured out the difference -- I also had to add `plugins: 'inlinepopups'` to the initializer.

Comment: oh, yes, of course - i forgot to add this - will update my answer

Comment: I should also note that this ultimately didn't solve the SSL issue.  It's still loading insecure data to generate the modal controls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to serve the javascript files from a secure location to avoid the issue of loading insecure content.